# Diffusion: Offer imported external repository over ssh/http via a diffusion clone url

Tags: phabricator

I have imported few private repos from Github to my Phabricator install. The clone url on Phabricator still shows the Github clone URL.

Is there a way to offer read-only copy from Phabricator via diffusion clone url?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported. Feel free to file a feature request:

https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/task/create/

Particularly, we'd be curious what your use case is. There's no technical reason we can't support this, but haven't seen anyone wanting to use Phabricator as a read-only mirror of some  other repository yet.

Comment: I will create a task and explain my use case in detail. Thanks for your time.